# Passing a Knockout Observable as a parameter to a JavaScript Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

My Knockoutjs code goes as following:

```
function chainModel(){
        var self = this;
        this.total_count = ko.observable();

        function get_total_count(number){
            $.ajax({
                type : "get",
                url : "./XYZ/abc.php",
                cache : false,
                data : {number: number},
                success : function(result){
                    self.total_count($.parseJSON(result));
                },
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    console.log("Error ! Unable to get step " + $number + " count." + "Error: " + errorThrown + ", Status: " + textStatus);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new chainModel());
```

Inside the get_total_count() function, I am assigning the ajax result to self.total_count observable. Instead, I would like to pass the observable too as an parameter to the get_total_count() function so that I can reuse the same function for more than one observable.

Comment: just out of curiosity: why are you using $ notation for the $number parameter? That is just a number? not a jQuery object

Comment: What prevents you from passing the observable as a parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a different approach which is using the the promise semantics of jQuery Ajax calls. Take a few minutes to familiarize yourself with [jQuery Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) if the concept is new to you, it's worth it.

*Quick note: By widely adopted convention, constructor names are `PascalCase` and all other names are `camelCase` in JavaScript. Don't use `underscore_separated` identifiers (nobody else does).*

```
function ChainModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.totalCount = ko.observable();
    self.otherCount = ko.observable();

    function getCount(number) {
        return $.get("./XYZ/abc.php", {number: number})
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error(
                "Error ! Unable to get step " + number + " count." + 
                "Error: " + errorThrown + ", Status: " + textStatus
            );
        });
    }

    getCount(1).done(self.totalCount);
    getCount(2).done(self.otherCount);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ChainModel());
```

Since knockout observables are in fact functions and calling them sets their value, you can directly use them as success callbacks in Ajax calls.

By returning the [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) from `getCount()`, you get access to the promise functions it exposes. So instead of passing in the target observable *into* `getCount()` you could pass it to the `.done()` callback, thus assigning the result of the Ajax call to it. Effectively this is separation of concerns and makes your code more flexible.

Other notes:

- You should not have to force `cache: false` in an Ajax call. Set the appropriate `Cache-Control` header on the server side and the browser won't cache the call.
- jQuery automatically parses the response for you, manually calling `$.parseJSON()` is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand why '$.paseJSON()' is not necessary assuming that my PHP function returns an array indexed by column number. If I don't use '$.parseJSON()' then it displays data as [{"1234"}] .

Comment: When jQuery receives a JSON encoded response then it decodes it automatically. If your response data *still* is JSON after that, then it's very probably that it's double-encoded on the server - effectively a bug you need to fix on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it as simple as passing the observable as an argument?

```
function chainModel(){
    var self = this;
    this.total_count = ko.observable();

    get_total_count(this.total_count, this.number);

    function get_total_count(observable, number){
        $.ajax({
            type : "get",
            url : "./XYZ/abc.php",
            cache : false,
            data : {number: number},
            success : function(result){
                observable($.parseJSON(result));
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log("Error ! Unable to get step " + number + " count." + "Error: " + errorThrown + ", Status: " + textStatus);
            }
        });
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new chainModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling this method "get_total_count()" via any event binding. If so, then you can pass entire data view model to this method.

```
<input data-bind="event:{ click: function(data,event){ get_total_count(data,event,total_count()); } }" />
```